# Using NSFetchRequest with complex NSPredicate in a NSFetchRequestController

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Im trying to implement something that I'm sure have been implemented a million times before, a search in the core data database, displayed in a table using a `fetchRequestController` and the `searchController`.

My problem is writing the `NSPredicate` for the `NSFetchRequest`. According to the `NSPredicate` guide by Apple, not everything you can do in Sqlite is possible with core data.
I have been trying to find a solution for some time, but maybe one of you can use his experience to help me.

CoreData DB description:
`Shops` has a MANY TO MANY relationship with `DiscountProgam`.

My use case is as follows: I need to filter out `Shops` who's name/address/zip/city contains the search string. that's the easy part.
The hard part is creating the section of the database I want to filter from, because I have an array of "active" `discountPrograms` UID's, and I only want `shops` that have one of the active discount programs in their "discountPrograms" set. So in pseudo code that would be:

FROM `Shops` who have at least one `discountProgram` who's uid IN `activeDiscountProgramsArray` WHERE name/address/zip/city CONTAINS searchString

Is this possible? am I over reaching the limits of predicates? 
If so, how could I do it differently?

Comment: UID is a property of `DiscountProgam`, or it's the managed object id? What predicate are you currently trying?

Comment: @Wain UID is a property of DiscountProgram. I am currently not working with a predicate, but doing everything in memory using a for-in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `NSPredicate` can analyse both the direct attributes of the target entity of a fetch and the attributes of its relationships. Try:

```
NSArray *validUIDs = ...;
NSString *searchTerm = ...;

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR zip CONTAINS[cd] %@) AND (SUBQUERY(discountProgram, $d, $d.UID IN %@).@count > 0)", searchTerm, searchTerm, validUIDs];
```